# How to save multiple form?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form and a button ... when the button is pressed in the form of adding the following fields:

```
<input type="text"  name="address" />
<input type="text"  name="city"    />
```

and if once again pressed the button in the form is again added field

I do not need to add in the estate []

```
<input type="text"  name="address[]" />
<input type="text"  name="city[]"    />
```

to get an array, because each field additions are stored in another table

how to sava all data in database

and it's all on laravel framework

Comment: explain properly what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the same **Name** element, then you'll need the brackets []

You can add an index **$i** like :

```
<input type="text"  name="address[$i]" />
<input type="text"  name="city[$i]" />
```

And then when you receive your data, you can use the same loop to get store your data in an array. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: and I will be saved in the database